# OmniFaces, FullAjaxExceptionHandler ERROR_PAGE_ERROR

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I have an application with primefaces 5.2, omnifaces 2.1, jsf 2.2, ejb and hibernate and wildfly 8.1, I'm having a big problem just one customer that is "*Oops!
A problem occurred during processing the ajax request. Subsequently, another problem occurred during processing the error page which should inform you about that problem.If you are the responsible web developer, it's time to read the server logs about the bug in the error page itself.*" and I was looking  for by problem and this message is constant of FullAjaxExceptionHandler class, but I don't know as resolved this problem.

I could see that it has a lot of this exception

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-64) Blocking request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /correspondente/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Broken Pipe
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:527)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:287)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken Pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:524) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.write(NioSocketConduit.java:159) [xnio-nio-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:561)
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.doWrite(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:171)
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.writeFinal(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:226)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:104) [xnio-api-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:172)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:582)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:616)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:525)
    ... 9 more
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
          version="2.2">

<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>br.com.virtualsistemas.correspondente.filter.CorrespondenteFilter</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>

<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
<application>
    <resource-handler>
        org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler
    </resource-handler> 
</application>
```

template.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
  xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
```

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="foundation.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="basic.css" />

<h:outputScript library="javascript" name="primefaces_locate.js" />
<h:outputScript library="javascript" name="sistema.js" />   
<h:outputScript library="javascript" name="jquery.maskMoney.js" />
<h:outputScript library="javascript" name="jquery.maskMoney.min.js" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="#{resource['img:icone.png']}" />
```

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show();" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide();" />
<p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" draggable="false" header="AGUARDE..." closable="false" resizable="false">
    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/img/ajax_loader.gif" />
</p:dialog>

<ui:include src="/paginas/sistema/motivoPausa.xhtml" />
<ui:include src="/paginas/sistema/menu.xhtml" />

<div class="row">
    <p:panel id="pnlConteudo" header="#{titulo}" styleClass="ui-panel-conteudo">
        <h:form id="formConteudo" prependId="false">
            <ui:insert name="conteudo" />
        </h:form>
        <ui:insert name="conteudo_sem_form" />

        <ui:insert name="modal" />

        <p:growl id="msg" widgetVar="msg" showDetail="false" life="10000" globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
    </p:panel>
</div>

<div class="row rodape">
    <div id="rodape" class="ui-panel-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all alinhamento_centro">
        <span class="ui-panel-title">Virtual Sistemas e Tecnologia Ltda. Copyright © 2014</span>
    </div>

    <div style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 2;">
        <p:clock mode="server" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will happen when the error page itself contains a bug which causes that it couldn't be rendered. Check the log for line `FullAjaxExceptionHandler: Well, another exception occurred during rendering error page '%s'. Trying to render a hardcoded error page now.`. The exception of interest should be logged directly thereafter.

Comment: I don't have a specific page that this error happens, I'm going to look for if in my log I have this exception that mentioned. I edited my post with my template and faces-config.